# Create a new data frame that will act as a dictionary with key and value pairs

Tags: r

I was playing with some data and trying to create a new data frame that contains key and value pairs that could be a dictionary. Here's some sample data and a quick manual solution.

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c("one", "one", "two", "two", "one"),
                col2 = c("AG", "AB", "AC", "AG", "AB"),
                col3 = c("F3", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F2") )
df
d1 = data.frame(vals = unique(df$col1))
d2 = data.frame(vals = unique(df$col2))
d3 = data.frame(vals = unique(df$col3))
d1 
d2 
d3
d1$name = "col1"
d2$name = "col2"
d3$name = "col3"
d1
d2
d3
rbind(d1,d2,d3)
```

Of course, this is a simple use case so real data is going to be a bit more mundane. For that reason, I was looking for a loop that could go through and set the key value pairs in a dictionary.

Most of my attempts have resulted in failure. Here's the format for my solution but I'm not sure how to dynamically create the new_df dictionary. Any suggestions?

```
new_df=data.frame()
prod.cols = c("col1", "col2", "col3")
for(col in prod.cols){
  if(col %in% colnames(df)){
    ## solution in here
  }
}

new_df
```

Comment: `unique(data.frame(name = names(df), vals = c(t(df))))`

Answer (score 5):

[`tidyr`](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr) makes this easy:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% gather(name, vals) %>% unique()

#    name vals
# 1  col1  one
# 3  col1  two
# 6  col2   AG
# 7  col2   AB
# 8  col2   AC
# 11 col3   F3
# 12 col3   F1
# 13 col3   F2
```

Answer (score 4):

alistaire's answer is quite elegant and readable.  Just for fun, here's a base R approach.  Not that efficiency is particularly important here, but this scales relatively well as more rows and columns are added:

My second and third approaches are nicer than my first, so I'm moving them to the top of the answer:

Approach # 2, implementing thelatemail's comment for a nice, efficient one-liner:

```
stack(lapply(df, function(ii) as.character(unique(ii))))
```

What's nice about this solution is that it first reduces the columns using `unique`, which makes less work for `as.character` and then for `stack`.

---

Approach # 3:  more concise and more efficient version of approach 2 that avoids the need for `unique` and character conversion by using `levels` to deal with the factor columns:

```
stack(lapply(df, levels))
```

---

First approach:

```
Reduce(rbind,
    lapply(seq_along(df), 
        function(ii) data.frame(vals = unique(df[, ii]), name = names(df)[ii])
    )
)

# vals name
#1 one col1
#2 two col1
#3  AG col2
#4  AB col2
#5  AC col2
#6  F3 col3
#7  F1 col3
#8  F2 col3
```

Using `do.call` instead of `Reduce` is roughly equivalent here:

```
do.call(rbind,
    lapply(seq_along(df), 
        function(ii) data.frame(vals = unique(df[, ii]), name = names(df)[ii])
    )
)
```

Comment: Looks like a `stack` operation to me - `unique(stack(lapply(df,as.character)))`

Comment: @thelatemail yea, you're right.  I had tried using `stack` but was missing the character conversion step.  I like this modification to avoid creating the larger structure before calling `unique`:  `stack(lapply(df, function(ii) as.character(unique(ii))))`.  Should be pretty efficient.  Wanna add an answer?

Comment: Your modification is very clever - feel free to just edit it in if you like. I don't need more imaginary internet points :-)

Comment: yes, your stack answer is nice... you should move it to the top of your answer less it gets missed

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(reshape2)
unique(melt(as.matrix(df))[-1])
```

Comment: you can use the `id` arg to save the as.matrix call... but it is of course irrelevant ;) `unique(reshape2::melt(df, id=0))`